# Deleting Inactive 5 days Old Files

Tags: bash, shell

My aim is to delete more than 5 days old files which are no longer used by any process.
As a starter I have written following script, but it does not work, says line 10 command not found.

```
HOME=~/var

cd $HOME

for f in `find . -type f`; do
  if [`lsof -n $f`]; then

       echo $f
  fi

done
```

Comment: You need to indicate the make time. Something like `mtime +5` could do.

Comment: Yes, but i was stuck on lsof line this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm ye its not being done properly try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

     DIR=$HOME/var
     ##########################################################
     ## files older than 5 days and recursive value set to 1 
     # for f in $(find  $DIR -mtime +5 -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
     ##########################################################
     for f in $(find  $DIR -type f); do
        # run lsof and look for pattern a-z send it to dev null
        lsof -n $f |grep [a-z] > /dev/null
        # If it was found the exit status will be 0 or success
        if  [ $? = 0 ]; then
           echo "$f in use -->"
        else
                echo "File $f not in use"
        fi
    done
```

In your script you had defined HOME as ~/var - using squigly line in scripting I would try and stay away from. Secondly you were changing an environment variable's value within your script.. Try from your command line

```
env|grep HOME
```

This new method is a lot cleaner

Now here is another pointer that may mean you need to make further changes...

Will your script be running in a cron job ? will it be running as a cron entry as this existing user ? if it is set for root to run then above will fail I will show you how:

```
echo $HOME
/home/myuser

sudo -i

echo $HOME
/root
```

notice how the ~ or $HOME value for home has changed.. so if you do decide to run it as a cron entry as another user then try this

```
scriptuser="your_user"
getent passwd $scriptuser|awk -F":" '{print $6}'
```

if it is the current user that is then sudo su - or sudo -i then executing script then try :

```
getent passwd $(logname)|awk -F":" '{print $6}'
```

Comment: wow..exactly what i wanted ...and thanks for explaining other nice bits as well :)